# Is there a way to read from Parquet files in hdfs into SqlContext from Mobius?

Tags: c#, apache-spark, parquet, mobius

I know in Scala , you can read in a parquet file as follows:

```
//Create Spark Context
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(sparkMaster)
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

 val pf = 
      sqlContext.read.parquet(hdfsDataUri + "test.parquet")
 pf.registerTempTable("test")
```

Is there a way to do this using Mobius (C# API for Spark)? I could only find a way to read in CSV files.
Ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[C# API for using Parquet in Apache Spark](https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius/blob/master/csharp/Adapter/Microsoft.Spark.CSharp/Sql/DataFrameReader.cs#L157) is available in [Mobius](https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius). Following is the C# implementation of the Apache Spark Scala code in your question:

```
        var sparkConf = new SparkConf().SetAppName(appName).SetMaster(sparkMaster);
        var sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
        var sqlContext = new SqlContext(sc);
        var pf = sqlContext.Read().Parquet(hdfsDataUri + "test.parquet");
        pf.RegisterTempTable("test");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read and write parquet files directly in .NET via https://github.com/elastacloud/parquet-dotnet

Comment: This is the better answer. Since Parquet.NET v3 release, arguably the best way to access Parquet.